# Function field, finite extension, isomorphism implies isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A$ be a function field in $1$ variable over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $B$ be a finite extension of $A$ of degree $[B : A]$. If $B \cong \mathbb{C}(x)$ over $\mathbb{C}$, then does it necessarily follow that $A \cong \mathbb{C}(x)$ over $\mathbb{C}$? Here, $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is the field of rational functions in $x$ whose coefficients are in $\mathbb{C}$.

**Thought.** Perhaps we want to use the fact that a function field in $1$ variable over an algebraically closed field $k$ is of genus $0$ if and only if $F \cong k(x)$ over $k$, somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This is [Lüroth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCroth%27s_theorem): any intermediate field between $K$ and $K(x)$ is a simple extension. Since we can assume $B=K(x)$, there exists $f\in K(x)$ such that $A=K(f(x))$ and finiteness of $[B:A]$ ensures $f(x)$ is transcendental over $K$; thus $A\cong K(x)$.

Note that $K$ being algebraically closed is not necessary.